# Ajuste de opacidade do fundo de painéis no vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Olá.
Eu estou tentando fazer um aplicativo no VB.NET em que é necessário um ajuste na opacidade de apenas o fundo de alguns "panels" para que eles fiquem meio transparentes, mas não invisíveis. Segue exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode ajustar propriedades de opacidade [alpha] na cor do painel:

```
Dim Opacity As Int32 = 50                      ' valor em porcentagem
Me.Color = Color.White 
Panel1.Color = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Black) 
Panel2.Color = Color.FromArgb(25, 100, 51, 62) ' opacidade-vermelho-verde-azul
```

Comment: Obrigado! Só mais uma pergunta: existe como aplicar essa transparência ao fundo de um form? Não consegui fazer como fiz nos panels.

Comment: Existe sim. Pela propriedade [Opacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx): `Form1.Opacity = 0.5`